# Openerp using the value of title in e-mail templates

Tags: email, odoo

i´m trying to use the title of the person in the e-mail template. But it does still not work

The name of the person works with this: ${object.partner_id.name}

So I tried to get the title with this: ${object.partner_id.title}

But this does not work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `${object.partner_id.title.name};`. `object.partner_id.title.name` is a table.